# Scala PlayFramework waiting for source changes. But Not responding

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I have modified the main.scala.html file in views of my app based on scala. I reverted the changes. But when I am running "~run" to open the play framework it is showing

```
 Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

It is not even responding from that stage. The program is working when I call my inputs from Restapi client postman. But the print statements are not displaying on the terminal of my MacOsx. The program is written on Java. It is a huge program, so I am not able to post it here. Any idea of recovering this?

Is this an error or application bug, as it is taking too much time .

Comment: If you use IDE such as Eclipse, did you try refreshing workspace?

Comment: @MonCalamari - I have restarted eclipse and MacOsx. Tried all possibilities. Still showing the same . Waiting for source changes.

Answer (score 2):

"Waiting for source changes" means your application is up and working. There must be some other problem.

Comment: Yeah. i checked that it is up and running for the comment "waiting for source changes". It is quite hard to understand for me. I have compiled seperately and run on a different port other than 9000. It is compiling successfully. But again when i hit "~run", I am stuck at "Waiting for source changes". I wold like to ask if there is any other way to explicitly tell Play framework to look or load my scala driver that i have installed man ually in my system ?

Comment: You're not stuck - that's what's meant to happen when you type `~run`, or are you expecting something else to show?

Comment: @artbistol . But it has been showing the same for more than 5hours. I stopped it atlast. Seems a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this using `iTerm2` instead of `terminal`, which worked for some time or maybe i was just more productive during that period. However, there is an issue on github regarding this problem (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3608). When using `activator`, the following line gets added to your `build.sbt`:

`fork in run := true`

Setting this to `false` or commenting it out, allowed me at least to have play recompile on page reload and show me my page, after firing it up with `sbt run`.

There is also a section regarding the live reloading of code on the migration guide for play, because they renamed the `playWatchService` in 2.5, but i have not tested this out yet.

see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#playWatchService-renamed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `play run` instead of `sbt ~run`

Answer (score 0):

~run is an sbt specific command and runs a sbt task. ~ Tells sbt to run in continuous mode. sbt is telling you that it is waiting for source changes, which will automatically be compiled.

When I run my application this message usually appears after the code is done. It's a development feature I guess. If you don't need it than don't use the `~` but:

```
sbt run
```